# How do I underline a TWebLabel using code in a Delphi TMS WEB Core project?

Tags: delphi, underline, tms, tms-web-core

I have a `TWebLabel` which I want to underline using code.

During design-time, I can underline it through the properties:

[image: Delphi Font Properties]

[image: WebLinkLabel1]

But in run-time, it's not showing as underlined:

[image: WebLinkLabel1]

How can I solve this underline issue or do this via code instead of a design-time property?

---

Here's what I've tried and the errors I got:

- `WebLinkLabel1.Font.Style.fsUnderline := True;`

  > [Error] illegal qualifier "." after "Style:set of TFontStyle"
- `WebLinkLabel1.Font.Style := fsUnderline;`

  > [Error] Incompatible types: got "TFontStyle" expected "set of TFontStyle""
- `WebLinkLabel1.Font.Style := [fsUnderline];`

  No error, but the label isn't underlined. It's not working.

---

What is the correct way to underline a `TWebLabel` in TMS WEB Core using Delphi?

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with TMS or web stuff. This is how VCL font styles have worked for three decades.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand It has to do with TMS WEB Core, because underlining a `TWebLabel` doesn't always work the same as in VCL if you check my answer. As an example, underlining using `Font.Style` doesn't work if the `ElementClassName` property contains anything.

Comment: No, @AndreasRejbrand is absolutely correct. Setting the `Font.Style` in Delphi and TMS Web Core work identically, and it's worked that way in Delphi since Delphi 1 was released. Your mention of the CSS in your answer doesn't change anything, because when you're using CSS, you're not setting `Font.Style` - you're changing attributes in the style sheet.

Comment: @KenWhite The question isn't asking about `Font.Style` specifically. It's asking about underlining text in a `TWebLabel`

Comment: The image you chose to include clearly indicates `Font.Style`.

Comment: @KenWhite Yes, to show what I have tried to do in order to underline the text on the label. But ultimately the question isn't about `Font.Style`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `Style` property requires a set.

So I needed to do the following in order to underline the `TWebLabel` using code:

```
WebLinkLabel1.Font.Style := [TFontStyle.fsUnderline];
```

---

But also note that if you have any CSS classes attached to the `TWebLabel` via the `ElementClassName` property, then the `Font.Style` won't work at all. In this case, you need to underline the `TWebLabel` using the following code:

```
WebLinkLabel1.ElementHandle.style.setProperty('text-decoration-line','underline');
```

---

Alternatively, if you're using [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/text/), then you can just add the `text-decoration-underline` class to the `ElementClassName` property on the `TWebLabel. That will also underline it.